# Get value from nearest (lower) integer

Tags: firebird

As jkavalik sais: I'm looking for "the greatest value not greater than". I have a table containing a kind of IDs and values like those

```
ID     value
101    A
2003   B
4005   C
```

- when searching for "2003" I want to get "B"
- when searching for "2004"I want to get "B", too.
- when searching for "2002" I want to get "A"

If a always had exact matching IDs i would write

```
SELECT value FROM table WHERE id = 2003
```

But is there a way to handle my problem describe above? I'm using firebird 2.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT FIRST 1 value FROM table WHERE id <= 2003 ORDER BY id desc
```

Get the greatest value not greater than.